# How to chain these two subscriptions

Tags: angular

```
this.filteredMetros = this.facCreateForm.controls['Metro'].valueChanges
          .startWith(null)
          .map(Name => Name ? this.filter(Name) : this.metros);

this.facCreateForm.controls['Metro'].valueChanges.subscribe(data=>this.onMetroChange(data));
```

Basically I want to have two event listeners to the formcontrol's valueChange 
property.

Comment: You can add a `.do(data=>this.onMetroChange(data))` before the .map() (assuming you end up subscribing to the first observable)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do the following. Subscribe to onChange on the entire form, and grab the needed value accordingly.

```
this.facCreateForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
  data=> { 
    data.Name ? this.filter(data.Name) : this.metros;
    this.onMetroChange(data.Metro);
  });
```

I am not sure why you want to start with null when you are expecting input from a form.